# Ordered selections problem - restaurant problem.

Tags: permutations

Question: A restaurant has five entrees, seven main courses, and ten desserts. In how many ways can you select two dishes on the condition that they must not both be from the same part of the menu?

The answer is 155.

I have no idea what qualifies as a dish. Is it the combination of an entree, main course, and dessert? or is it only selecting 2 options from the 3 given e.g. (entree and main course, or, main course and dessert)?

Comment: Given the answer, it sounds like selecting $2$ options from the $3$... You have $5\times 7 + 5\times 10 + 7\times 10 = 35+50+70=155$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. I got lost in the wording of the problem, but that reasoning makes sense.